# Bottomsheet Dialog having Recycler View and Buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, bottom-sheet

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/dp_15">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_button_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_20"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_yes"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/cornered_green_bg"
            android:padding="@dimen/dp_15"
             >
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_yes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fontPath="ProximaNova-Semibold.otf"
            android:text="@string/yes"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp_18"
            />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/tv_yes"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_driver_request_coming_accept"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_10"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_no"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_10"
            android:background="@drawable/cornered_red_bg"
            android:padding="@dimen/dp_15"
            >
            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_no"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:fontPath="ProximaNova-Semibold.otf"
                android:text="@string/yes"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sp_18"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/tv_no"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_driver_request_coming_reject"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_10"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_data"
        android:layout_above="@id/ll_button_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[This is what i have to acheive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2Jb8.png)

I have to make a Bottomsheet Dialog having Recyler View and Buttons which have to be shown below the bottomsheet always but the problem is the buttons only show up when dialog is expanded to screens height.
One Solution i found is to give static heaight to recycler View but i dont wanna do that. 
Is there any Solution to avoid giving predefined height to recycler view so that my buttons are always Visible at the bottom of the Dialog?

Comment: I think its better to show reference images what you want to achieve and what you already have now.... and some piece of code obviously

Comment: I think its better to show reference images what you want to achieve and what you already have now.... and some piece of code obviously

Comment: @FaisalNaseer Added the picture

Comment: have you tried setting `setPeekHeigh`t for Bottomsheet?

Comment: i have tried setpeekHeight but the buttons only when the sheet is expanded.